# Sql function to make noun plural

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Is there any function in SQL Server which change the noun from singular to plural form?

Comment: That would be difficult (in English, anyway) owing to the irregularity of pluralites. Cat->Cats, Mouse->Mice, Goose->Geese, Person->People...

Comment: In what language? :) Sure, standard doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there a SQL function that understands grammar for a given language???  No :)

Comment: In general, I'd consider this a "display" issue, and would avoid putting the logic in SQL Server.

Comment: out of curiosity how do you plan on identifying that a word is a noun?

Answer (score 6):

SQL itself doesn't have anything like this - but you could try to use the .NET [PluralizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx) introduced in .NET 4 - the same functionality that the Entity Framework uses to pluralize/singularize table names to object names.

You would have to write a SQL-CLR assembly to tap into the pluralization services, but it definitely seems like a doable thing!

Comment: Is it possible to use .NET 4.0 assemblies in SQL Server CLR?

Comment: @MartinSmith - SQL CLR is currently (SQL 2008R2) limited to version 3.5 of the framework.  The System.Data.EntityDesign assembly targets 4.0 (see my answer below)

Comment: @EBarr:guess we'll have to wait for SQL Server 2012 then.....it'll have SQL CLR v4 built-in

Answer (score 4):

That function does not exist in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

The function does not exist in SQL Server, as @aF mentioned.   The one place I know if it existing is in Entity Framework 4+.  The pluralization object can actually be [instantiated and used](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/19/entity-framework-40-pluralization/).

SQL has the capacity to  run CLR code--through SQL CLR.   The main problem is that SQL CLR is limited to the .NET Framework 3.5.  So you would either need to write some .net 4 code that operates on your tables.  Alternately, you could use a product like Reflector and reverse engineer a 3.5 compatible version and run it inside SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Pluralize 
(
    @noun nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @QueryString nvarchar(4000)
SET @QueryString = N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"' + @noun + N'")'
RETURN
(SELECT TOP 1 display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@QueryString,1033,0,0))

END
GO

SELECT noun,
       dbo.Pluralize(noun)
FROM   (VALUES('cat'),
              ('mouse'),
              ('goose'),
              ('person'),
              ('man'),
              ('datum')) nouns(noun)
```

Returns

```
noun   
------ ------------------------------
cat    cats
mouse  mice
goose  geese
person persons
man    men
datum  data
```

Unfortunately it just relies on observation that the `TOP 1` expansion term for the noun is the plural form. I doubt that this is documented anywhere.

Comment: When I try this same `dbo.Pluralize` function definition, instead of `cats` the function returns `cat's`. Ditto for `person's` and `man's`. It also makes every result lower-case irrespective of the input argument's casing.

Comment: `Butterfly` is “pluralized” to `butterflied`.

Comment: @CalvinDale - it was relying on an undocumented observation about the behaviour of  `TOP 1` on the version I tested on 6 years ago. Looks like things have changed since and either additional expansions have been added or the order of the results of  `SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"Butterfly")',1033,0,0)`  has changed

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it looks like there isn't a way to reliably pluralize using this function.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DECLARE @PluralVersion nvarchar(128) = ''
    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(128) = 'MyTableName'        
    DECLARE @NounVersions TABLE(Term nvarchar(128) NOT NULL)
    DECLARE @QueryString nvarchar(4000) SET @QueryString = N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"' + @TableName + N'")'
    INSERT INTO @NounVersions
    SELECT TOP 10 display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@QueryString,1033,0,0)
    SELECT TOP 1 @PluralVersion = Term  FROM @NounVersions WHERE Term Not Like '%''%' AND RIGHT(Term,1) = 's'
    SET @PluralVersion = UPPER(LEFT(@PluralVersion,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(@PluralVersion,2,LEN(@PluralVersion)))
    SELECT @PluralVersion
```

I know this is an old thread, but thought I would post anyways. Based on what Martin started, I expanded it and so far it is doing an OK job. I would not say it is perfect. This is used for pluralizing table names so it is  very controlled

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use this for display purposes?
Something like "*Your search returned 1 **result***" / "*Your search returned 4 **results***" ?

If yes, I wouldn't do it like that.
Finding or writing a function that does this correctly for all special cases (let alone in several languages) is nearly impossible, and storing each needed text once in singular and once in plural form isn't much better.

At work, I'm dealing with multiple languages and lots of dynamically generated sentences like this a lot, and I found that completely avoiding the distinction of singular/plural forms at all is the easiest solution to manage:

"*Number of results for this search: 1*"

Answer (score 0):

**Nope, but it would be pretty easy to make a table for this if you have a limited set of words to check.**

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Plurals
( 
  id int IDENTITY,
  singular varchar(100),
  plural varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Plurals
VALUES
('cat', 'cats'),
('goose', 'geese'),
('man', 'men'),
('question', 'questions')
```

Alternatively, you could make the table just be exceptions, i.e. words that can't be pluralized with the simple addition of an `s` - then you could do an `EXISTS` check on that table, if it's not there then add an `s` and if it is then lookup the plural.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this.  Probably not perfect but it works for me.  And it returns with same capitalization as it was called.

```
create function dbo.udfPlural(@Int int
                           , @Item varchar(47))
returns varchar(50)
as
begin

   -- VARS...
   declare @Ninth char(1)
   declare @Tenth char(1)
   declare @Reply varchar(50)

   -- ONLY FOR PLURALS...
   if (@Int <> 1)
   begin
      -- LAST AND PENULTIMATE LETTERS...
      set @Ninth = ''
      set @Tenth = ''
      if (len(@Item) >= 2) set @Ninth = substring(@Item, len(@Item) - 1, 1)
      if (len(@Item) >= 1) set @Tenth = substring(@Item, len(@Item), 1)

      -- APPLY S/IES...
      if (@Tenth = 's')
         set @Reply = @Item + 'es'
      else if (@Tenth = 'y')
         if (charindex(@Ninth, 'AEIOU') > 0)
            set @Reply = @Item + 's'
         else
            set @Reply = substring(@Item, 1, len(@Item) - 1) + 'ies'
      else
         set @Reply = @Item + 's'
   end

   -- ASSEMBLE...
   set @Reply = ltrim(str(@Int)) + ' ' + @Reply

   -- DONE...
   return @Reply

end
```